# andoid studio kotlin - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: api, kotlin, request, get, retrofit

i am new to kotlin and i'm trying to call an api that has a array form ["value1","value2"] to display in my main activity textView and i keep getting this error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
can someone help i'm using kotlin

this is the Data Class:

```
data class ApiValuesItem(

    val values:Array<String?>

)
```

this is my interface:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("values")
    fun getApiValue(): Call<ApiValuesItem?>

}
```

and this is what i wrote in the mainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        
       const val BASE_URL = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/sfa/api/"
    }
    
    
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

get_Api.setOnClickListener {
getApiValues()
}
}

private fun getApiValues() {
val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.build()
.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getApiValue()
    
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<ApiValuesItem?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ApiValuesItem?>,
                response: Response<ApiValuesItem?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!
    
               val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
                for (ApiValues in responseBody){
                   myStringBuilder.append(ApiValues.values)
                   myStringBuilder.append(", ")
               }
                Api_Res.text = myStringBuilder
    
               }
    
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiValuesItem?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","onFailure: "+t.message)
                Api_Res.text = t.message
            }
        })
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Please post the json you have.

Comment: @GowthamKK this is the contents of the Json:  ["value1","value2"]

Comment: Please check my answer. Hope it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json:

> ```
> ["value1","value2"]
> ```

This is actually json array of strings.

If you define like below, it will be expecting json object. In that object , it will be expecting String Array with key **"values"**

```
data class ApiValuesItem(
    val values:Array<String?>
)
```

You model class will be mapped like this.

```
{"values":["value1","value2"]}
```

But your root is directly an array.

So instead of `Callback<ApiValuesItem?>` you should make it as any `Iterable<String>`. You can use arraylist like below.

```
Callback<ArrayList<String>?>
Call<ArrayList<String>?>
Response<ArrayList<String>?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and yes it worked the way you explained it. thank you